# package httr add_headers. httr::get() vs cURL

Tags: curl, http-headers, httr

I want to do a httr::GET() with a url and 2 headers. I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

using cURL, the following works:

```
curl -X GET "https://my.url.com/v1/objects/object_4/records" \
  -H "X-Myapp-Application-Id: xyzz1abc123" \
  -H "X-Myapp-REST-API-Key: xyzzy-12345-abcde"
```

I have tried many versions of

```
object_4<-get("https://my.url.com/v1/objects/object_4/records", add_headers(.headers=c('X-Myapp-Application-Id= xyzz1abc123','X-Myapp-REST-API-Key= xyzzy-12345-abcde')))
```

with :, or with =, with single quotes, double quotes, quotes around 'key = value', 'key' = 'value', "key = value", 'key: value' etc.

What is the proper syntax to convert by cURL code to httr::get()

thanks!

Comment: What happened with `headers = c('X-Myapp-Application-Id' = 'xyzz1abc123','X-Myapp-REST-API-Key' = 'xyzzy-12345-abcde')` ?

Answer (score 0):

object_4<-get("https://my.url.com/v1/objects/object_4/records", add_headers(.headers=c('X-Myapp-Application-Id= xyzz1abc123','X-Myapp-REST-API-Key= xyzzy-12345-abcde')))

GET ,
not get;
'X-Myapp-Application-Id'= 'xyzz1abc123','X-Myapp-REST-API-Key'= 'xyzzy-12345-abcde'
not
'X-Myapp-Application-Id= xyzz1abc123','X-Myapp-REST-API-Key= xyzzy-12345-abcde'